# Indexing / interpolation

Tags: python, image, opencv, indexing, interpolation

I am working on a image processing script that takes some pixel values and changes their location. my script returns me with pixel locations that arent integers, making it impossible to create an image array where I can simply plug in the piel value at their respective index.

I am looking to interp2d to do this.

for example I have a x,y,value matrix called 'scan'

scan=[[1.25, 1.25, 49],[4.65, 6.34, 154]...etc]]

```
  scan[:,0]=Xs #array of x values
  scan[:,1]=Ys #array of y values
  scan[:,2]=Vs #array of pixel values
```

which I need to interpolate onto a uniform 10x10 grid to show as an image.

I am currently trying to use interp2d as

```
f=interpolate.interp2d(scan[:,0],scan[:,1],scan[:,2])
image=f(range(10),range(10))
```

I have many points, some are in and out of bounds of the uniform image i am trying to map to

Thanks,
Niall

Comment: Please can you explain the application where you are trying to do this. This will give a better overview on what you are trying to achieve and why?

Comment: I am trying to manually transform an image using a 3x3 matrix. To obtain the new pixel location, I have to multiply the transformation matrix by [x,y,1].

This returns [x',y',constant]. I then divide this array by the constant will gives me [x',y',1] where x' is the new x coordinate, y' is the new y coordinant.

I have to then use x' and y' as the new indices for the pixel, but they aren't floats. I need to interpolate a grid with steps of 1 to show my image.

Comment: Hi, I am a little confused as what you are trying to do is nothing but computing a homography and then applying perspective transformation. There is function warpPerspective for that in opencv. For opencv 3.1, this is the link: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpperspective

Comment: Thanks, I've been using that but I need to do this manually. I am just looking for a way to use interpolation to lay a uniform grid over non-uniformly spaced points that have x,y,and pixel values.